# javascript to dynamically change the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

Attached the screenshot of my web page.
In that picture, under Regression type dropdown list box, there are three values consider 1, 2 and 3
So if I select 1 or 2, drop down below that "F1" should not appear. If value3, then it should appear.

To do this I have added onload under body tag.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class = "cl-regr" id="div-regr">
        <select name = "regr" id="drop-regr">
                                    <option selected="selected" disabled>-----Select-----</option>
                                    <option value = "1"> ips </option>
                                    <option value = "2"> ips sanity </option>
                                    <option value = "3"> Features </option>

                            </select>
        </div>

         <div class = "cl-ftr" id="div-ftr" onchange="displayFeatureList()">
                  <select name = "ftr" class = "cl2" id="drop-ftr">
                         <option value = "f1"> F1 </option>
                         <option value = "f2"> F2 </option>
                         <option value = "f3"> F3 </option>
                         <option value = "f4"> F4 </option>
                 </select>
         </div>
```

RESPECTIVE SCRIPT IN SEPARATE .js FILE:

```
function func1(){
        $(".cl-ftr").each(function() {
                var that  = $(this);
                that.find("div.cl2").style.visibility="hidden";
        });
};

function displayFeatureList(){

        var d_obj = document.getElementById("drop_reg").value;
        var op = d_obj.options[d_obj.selectedIndex].value;
        if (op == 3){
                document.getElementById("drop_ftr").style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else{
                document.getElementById("drop_ftr").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }

};
```

where I'm calling func1 from body tag

```
<body onload="func1()">
```

Problems I'm facing are, 
1)Whenever the page loads, the "F1" dropdown list box of first row is hiding (ie, ClientIP - 10.213.174.90)
2) If I change the value, displayFeatureList function is not making any effects.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Your onChange event `displayFeatureList()` is registered to the wrong element. It is set for the parent `div` instead of the `select`

Answer (score 0):

you are **syntax** was wrong

1. `$(this)` is jquery object `style.visiblity` its dom function
2. Use with [`css()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiT8szx24jVAhXJM48KHRdHBZsQFgg7MAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fcss%2F&usg=AFQjCNGpX40YDkFD6xGrnN6xrgMbkgkIvQ) jquery function .`style.visiblity` is not a jquery object.
3. For better my suggestion use css `.cl2{visiblity:hidden}` instead of js
4. `cl2` class in select element not with `div` so remove the `div` with `cl2` in selector like `find('cl2')`
5. fix the id name **typo** `-` instead of `_`
6. Add change event with first select
7. Get the value from dropdown direct call the `selectelement.value`.no need specify index

```js
function func1() {
  $(".cl-ftr").each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.find(".cl2").css('visibility', "hidden");
  });
};

function displayFeatureList() {
  var d_obj = document.getElementById("drop-regr").value
  if (d_obj == '3') {
    document.getElementById("drop-ftr").style.visibility = 'visible';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("drop-ftr").style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="func1()">
  <div class="cl-regr" id="div-regr">
    <select name="regr" id="drop-regr" onchange="displayFeatureList()">
                                    <option selected="selected" disabled>-----Select-----</option>
                                    <option value = "1"> ips </option>
                                    <option value = "2"> ips sanity </option>
                                    <option value = "3"> Features </option>

                            </select>
  </div>

  <div class="cl-ftr" id="div-ftr" >
    <select name="ftr" class="cl2" id="drop-ftr">
                         <option value = "f1"> F1 </option>
                         <option value = "f2"> F2 </option>
                         <option value = "f3"> F3 </option>
                         <option value = "f4"> F4 </option>
                 </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With all respect, your code quality is not very good.

- It's filled with typos (changing `_` to `-`, missing single letters for ids etc.) This way, nothing will ever work. Take more care.
- An `id` has to be unique. If an `id` appears twice in the same HTML document, 
  the document is not valid by definition. (It still loads though, but you have to expect errors.) You maybe want to keep the `id`s an add a dynamic number (row number)to keep them unique
- If you use jQuery, use it by default. Don't mix up jQuery(`func1()`) and JS DOM methods(`displayFeatureList`)

I reduced your code to the following (I commented the whole JS code for better understanding):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //run when page loading is complete
  $(".regessionTypeCell").each(function() { //for each regessionTypeCell class (parent div, might be a table cell in your case)
    $(this).find(".drop-regr").change(function(event) { //set onChange function for the containing drop-regr class
      var conditionalDropdown = $(this).find(".cl-ftr"); //get the conditional dropdown element
      if ($(this).find(".drop-regr").val() == 3) { //if selected index is equal 3
        conditionalDropdown.show(); //show dropdown
      } else {
        conditionalDropdown.hide(); //hide dropdown
      }
    }.bind($(this))); //bind this to the inner function
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="regessionTypeCell">
  <div class="cl-regr">
    <select name="regr" class="drop-regr">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>-----Select-----</option>
    <option value="1"> ips </option>
    <option value="2"> ips sanity </option>
    <option value="3"> Features </option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="cl-ftr" style="display:none">
    <select name="ftr" class="drop-ftr">
    <option value="f1"> F1 </option>
    <option value="f2"> F2 </option>
    <option value="f3"> F3 </option>
    <option value="f4"> F4 </option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="regessionTypeCell">
  <div class="cl-regr">
    <select name="regr" class="drop-regr">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>-----Select-----</option>
    <option value="1"> ips </option>
    <option value="2"> ips sanity </option>
    <option value="3"> Features </option>
  </select>
  </div>

  <div class="cl-ftr" style="display:none">
    <select name="ftr" class="drop-ftr">
    <option value="f1"> F1 </option>
    <option value="f2"> F2 </option>
    <option value="f3"> F3 </option>
    <option value="f4"> F4 </option>
  </select>
  </div>
</div>
```